# WCF Data Services - "Bad Request - Error in query syntax."

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services

I have this url in my browser :

```
https://localhost/service.svc/Add?clientGuid=cf4cca29-e144-4e6a-8485-792f809d84cc
                                 &contractId=6
                                 &endSession=False
                                 &GroupIds='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
                                 &FamilyIds=
                                 &PartNumbers=
```

and I have the following method in my web service machine :

```
[WebGet]
public void Add(string clientGuid,
                int contractId,
                bool endSession,
                string GroupIds,
                string FamilyIds,
                string PartNumbers)
{
   ...
}
```

but accessing the url gives me the following exception : "400 Bad Request - Error in query syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation ignored for GUID:

```
https://localhost/service.svc/Add?clientGuid=guid'cf4cca29-e144-4e6a-8485-792f809d84cc'
                                  &contractId=6
                                  &endSession=False
                                  &GroupIds='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
                                  &FamilyIds=
                                  &PartNumbers=
```

Comment: even with the quotation marks, it still throws the exception.

Comment: Maybe false instead of False, See this http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/overview#AbstractTypeSystem

Comment: Or modify clientGuid=guid'cf4cca29-e144-4e6a-8485-792f809d84cc'

Comment: OK,I glad,But only yes! Vote up pas chi mishe?

Comment: but I call my service using the following code :             string requestString = string.Format("Add?clientGuid={0}&contractId={1}&endSession={2}&GroupIds={3}&FamilyIds={4}&PartNumbers={5}",
                "'" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "'", ContractId, endSession, GroupIds, FamilyIds, PartNumbers);                                                                      service.Execute<string>(new Uri(requestString, UriKind.Relative));  the parameter endSession is False with a big F, how to change it to lower case ?